# Using JS to find select (drop down list) with only one option and then select the one option by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

In my SPA site I dynamically adding several select (dropdown list \ combo-boxes) tags to the page. 
What I need to do is to check which one of them have only one option (empty string as option caption doesn't count) and for those select them by default.
I also use Knockout binding and need the selected value to be properly bind to the correlated variable .
For example, if those are the select tags:

```
<div>
  <select for="required" data-bind="options: list1, value: val1, optionsCaption: ''">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <select for="required" data-bind="options: list2, value: val2, optionsCaption: ''">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The code should automatically pick the only option in the first select.
I tried using this code:

```
var chooseDefaultValues = function() {
            var relevantComboBoxes = $("select[for='requiredComboBox']");
            for (var i = 0; i < relevantComboBoxes.length; i++) {
                var currentComboBox = relevantComboBoxes[i];
                if (currentComboBox.disabled) continue; //Skip disabled combo-boxes
                if (currentComboBox.length === 1) { //If there is only one child, select it
                    currentComboBox.selectedIndex = 0;
                }
                if (currentComboBox.length === 2) { //If there are twon childern:
                    if ($(currentComboBox.firsChild).text().trim() === "") { //If the first one is the empty option caption pick the second child
                        currentComboBox.selectedIndex = 1; //As it is the only choice there is
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is that it shows in the select box the right value, but it doesn't populate the binded variable.
I also tried to replace the line:

```
currentComboBox.selectedIndex = 0
```

by

```
currentComboBox[0].click()
```

But it didn't help...

Your help will be appretiate :)

Comment: For one thing, the `for` attribute is invalid for `select` elements. But that's not likely to be the problem.

Comment: You don't want to do this at the DOM level. You want to do it at the Knockout viewmodel level.

Comment: `required` attribute is a good replacement for your `for="required"`

Comment: @nnnnnn I use Knockout binding, In the select tag the bind will be to the variable mentioned after 'value:'

Comment: i advice to do it in `ko` way entirely don't mix up . use using data-bind `options: list1` it should contain all `options` data you don't need to mention `<option>` tag

Comment: coudl you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net